# Accessing the PWD inside a thor task

Tags: ruby, bash

In my main thor file, I call this code

**script.rb**

```
# this works
current_dir = Dir.getwd 

# this changes directory into the tasks
Dir.chdir(#{pwd}/tasks) {
  IO.popen("thor #{ARGV * ' '}") do |io|
    while (line = io.gets) do
       puts line
    end
    io.close
  end
}
```

**tasks/example.rb**

```
require 'thor'

class Git < Thor
  include Thor::Actions

  desc 'test', 'test'
  def test
    puts Dir.getwd # this is showing my tasks folder
  end
end
```

Inside `example.rb` How can I get access to the `Dir.getwd` value of the `script.rb` and not of the `example.rb` (this is wrong since it is running inside the Dir.chdir).

I tried global variables and such but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you pass it as an arg when you call example.rb? Alternatively you could just stuff it into ENV and pull it out.

Comment: Good idea, thank you!